# How to fix GWT CellTree disappears (bug)?

Tags: gwt

When you click in white space between two nodes, cellTree disappears. Bug is even in Showcase gwt example.
Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found discussion on http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6359

Suggested fix worked for me:

```
    import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTree.Resources;
```

in module...

```
    Resources resource = GWT.create(Resources.class);
    StyleInjector.injectAtEnd("."+resource.cellTreeStyle().cellTreeTopItem()+" {margin-top: 0px;}"); // Not the best code
    tree = new CellTree(treeModel, treeModel.getRoot(),resource);
```

Comment: you better create custom resources, that's rather ugly